# Javascript form validation total 100

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to validate the form below to make sure the total of all the inputs is exactly 100 and only numbers. So far I can validate if it's over 100. but when I try to validate if below 100, I get the alert before all the values are input.

```
<form name="myForm" id="form1">
              <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1" class="hvr-pop"/>  <br>
             <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" class="hvr-pop"/> <br>
             <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3" class="hvr-pop"/>  <br>
              <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty4" class="hvr-pop"/>  <br>
              <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty5" class="hvr-pop"/><br>
             <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty6" class="hvr-pop"/><br>


            <textarea type="text" name="total" id="total" class="hvr-pop" readonly placeholder="Must total 100"></textarea>  
      </form>


<script>
     function findTotal(){
            "use strict";
            var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
            var tot=0;
            for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
                if(parseInt(arr[i].value)) {
                    tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);

                    }
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('total').value = tot;



            // check that weightage scores = 100

            if (tot > 100) {
                    alert("Please make sure numbers total 100");
                    document.getElementByName("qty").value = null;

                    return false;
                }


        }

    <script>
```

Comment: Two ways you can prevent this from happening: 1. Put in if statement at the beginning of `findTotal()` that exits the function if any `qty` input is empty. 2. have findTotal() run from a button click, which you can click after entering all the `qty`s.

Comment: Thanks, yes I thought of option 2, but it is not optimal. I think option 1 would not work because as the user inputs values, findTotal() is adding each one. There will be empty values as it calculates

Comment: In that case, just check if any of the inputs are empty while you're looping through them and set a flag. After the loop, if flag is true, return/don't call `alert()`

Answer (score 0):

```
let total = [...document
  .getElementById('form1')
  .querySelectorAll('input')]
  .reduce((acc, el) => acc += parseInt(el.value, 10), 0)

if (total !== 100)
  return console.warn('total inputs not 100')
```

Comment: Would I replace "document.getElementById('total').value = tot;



            // check that weightage scores = 100

            if (tot > 100) {
                    alert("Please make sure numbers total 100");
                    document.getElementByName("qty").value = null;

                    return false;
                }" with what you have above?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!